# SAP UI5 , bindItems doesn't work as expected (It's binding all items to every element)

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, data-binding, sapui5

I'm very new to UI5 and I have a huge problem now with the databinding.

Firstly I've written a service where I can get datas from DB.

If I make a URL request it works fine, without anyerrors.

And in order to use my service I have 2 different ajax calls in 2 different places,

in one of them the .bindItems method works just fine as expected. at the other one it just binds all of the results to every single element.

Just like at the photo. From my AJAX Call I get  a JSON with 8 objects and every object has `ATC-Code` value. What I want to do is  printing  every ATC-Code to only one item.

[image]

my JSON Reply on browser looks like this[image]

my AJAX Request Code ;

```
jQuery.ajax({
            url: aUrl,
            method: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
                //add new fields to Model
                myData = data;
                $.each(data.results.rs, function(key, val) {
                    val.FAVORED = false;
                    val.COMPARED = false;
                });

                console.log("myData => ", myData);
                //console.log(aData);
                // Model und BindingContext (Daten) verbinden
                oModel.setData(myData);
                console.log("oModel =>", oModel);
            },

            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                sap.ui.core.BusyIndicator.hide();
                sap.ui.commons.MessageBox.show("Fehler: " + errorThrown);
                return;
            }
```

I also have a template written for this

```
    var oTemplate1 = new sap.m.ColumnListItem({
            cells: [
                new sap.m.Text({
                    text: "{KEY_ATC}"
                }),
                new sap.m.Text({
                    text: "{KEY_ATC_NAME}"
                }),
                new sap.m.Text({
                    text: "not in database"
                }),
                new sap.m.Text({

                    text: "not in db"
                })
            ]
        });
```

The way I try to bind items is  :

```
this.byId("tableDetail1").setModel(oModel).bindItems("results/rs/0", oTemplate1);
```

In case you wonder where is `tableDetail1` , it is in my view.js file.But It is not the part of this problem.

Would be very happy if someone could tell me why it prints everything and not only the one data that I need

PS: `.bindItems("results/rs/0", oTemplate1);`
 I am using this but if I change it to `results/rs/0/0`  it doesnt show anything at all

Comment: I would be happy to know who and why did give a  - vote to this question ?

Comment: "bindItems" was designed to bind a collection (array) to the list. So it is very obvious and expected that you get - all the items are in the table. I cannot understand why do you want to display the 1 item and even if so, why don't you use a form or something like that - to display a single object.

Comment: But  what does actually the `/`  ? does it navigate in an array or in an object ?  or both ?

Comment: "/" navigates to the property in absolute manner (in the root of the model). So if the UI control has the context set, then in order to get the properties relatively to the upper context, the binding path must not contain the "/".